# Unable to login with SSH

Tags: macos, authentication, ssh, server

I have an old OS X Server 10.4 with some websites on it. When this was setup several years ago I got help from a friend that turned on some kind of protection, so that only my computer was able to reach the server.

However, I have switched computer since then and now I'm not able to login to it via SSH any longer. When I try I get "Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive)."

Now my only option is to interact with the server IRL or ARD, but I would really like SSH.

I have modified the /etc/sshd_config file to no avail (probably because I'm just guessing and really don't know what I'm doing).

In short: I want to be able to login (with a password of course) from whatever device and where ever I am to my server. Ie, turn off the "only-this-computer-should-be-able-to-login-to-this-server"-function.

TIA,
Andreas

Comment: i am no expert in this, but i have tow ideas of what this could be: 1. MAC address filter 2. mandatory public-private key encryption. maybe read up on these two things, and find out how they are configured, and see if that is the case on your server.

Answer (score 0):

AHA! I found two lines at the bottom of the config file:

PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no

Changing these to "yes" solved the problem.

I realize that anyone that knows the password are able to login now, but I'm willing to take that risk. After all, I'm not CIA... ;)